# Nette how to subtract timestamp from current date

Tags: date, nette, latte

how can i subtract number of days (timestamp|date'z') from current day (date('z')) in latte? I've tryes to use var but that does not like the formating (z).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Latte filters, unlike function calls, are not something that can be applied to any part of an expression – they are only optional feature of the variable printing macro.

```
{expression_to_be_printed|filter1|filter2|filter3}
```

`date` filter mostly just [calls `format` method](https://github.com/nette/latte/blob/8c6adb0c886f1fd763d24c68aa584366c2c6a006/src/Latte/Runtime/Filters.php#L406) so you can use it directly:

```
{(new DateTime())->format('z') - $timestamp->format('z')}
```

This, however, will not work if the `$timestamp` lies in a different year. 
To fix this, you can use `DateTime`’s [`diff`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php) method. `DateInterval`, returned by the method, can then be formatted using [`format`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/dateinterval.format.php) method which provides difference in the number of days through `%a` formatting string.

```
{$timestamp->diff(new DateTime())->format('%a')}
```

Fortunately, the `date` filter also allows formatting intervals.

```
{$timestamp->diff(new DateTime())|date:'%a'}
```

Admittedly, this looks kind of ugly. A better way would be to define a custom filter so you could just use `{$post->timestamp|daysAgo}`. See [Latte docs](https://latte.nette.org/en/#toc-filters) about creating your own filters.

Comment: Creating the latte filter looks better. Thank you.